# How to use XSLTViewWebPart in Provider Hosted App in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-online, provider-hosted-app

How to use `XSLTViewWebPart` in provider hosted app or is there any alternative solution to do that.

I have a requirement to use OOB context menu.

Comment: Edit the page and add the list app. This will add the `XsltListViewWebPart` to the page.

Comment: can you please let me know how to add list app in page, if you have any code?

Comment: Edit the page and add new webpart. You don't need any code to achieve this.

Comment: but I am developing custom provider hosted app. I dont have any fixed page to edit and add the list.

Comment: And also, list is not fixed. it would be anything list, library..

Answer (score 2):

Here is the code to add `XsltListViewWebPart` to a page in app:

```
<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" FrameType="None" ID="TaskListZone" >
<WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart runat="server"
ListUrl="Lists/WorkflowTaskList"
IsIncluded="True"
PageType="PAGE_NORMALVIEW"
Default="False"
ViewContentTypeId="0x"
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>
```

See this for more info: http://www.greggalipeau.com/2013/12/25/adding-list-views-to-sharepoint-2013-apps/

Comment: Just a note, this will work in the app web of the app, but not in the provider hosted web.

Comment: WebPartPages namespace is within the Microsoft.SharePoint which is not supported in Provider hosted app. it's only support the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client namespace and in that WebPartPages is not available.

Comment: You can still create a page in the app web of a provider hosted app to use for the xslt if you want to. But as you say, it is a SharePoint we part that it is not possible to use outside of SharePoint (as in your own web site in the provider hosted app)

Comment: I am afraid but I think we cant use xsltviewwebpart in provider hosted app event in any page. because while adding the Microsoft.SharePoint reference in page and try to add the xslt web part within the page, we are getting the error in page load. if you have any other way, please share with example.